# PHP $_POST gets stored as the word 'Array'

Tags: php, arrays, post

I am having issues with storing input data from a form. All that is stored in the database is the word 'Array'. Seems I have to do something with the post data before it can be stored properly. Can't get it to work properly. And any help is appreciated. Here is the code that handles the input form.

```
<?php

session_start();

/* variables */
$a1 = $_POST['value1'];
$a2 = $_POST['value2'];
$a3 = $_SESSION['user_id'];

/* connect */
$mysqli = new mysqli("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* prepare statement */
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET column1 =? WHERE user_id=? "))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if (!($stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET column2 =? WHERE user_id=? "))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

/* bind parameters for markers */
if (!$stmt->bind_param("ss", $a1, $a3)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
if (!$stmt2->bind_param("ss", $a2, $a3)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt2->errno . ") " . $stmt2->error;
}

/* loop and execute */
foreach($a1 as $key => $value){
            $key++;     
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }
    }

foreach($a2 as $key => $value){
            $key++;     
        if (!$stmt2->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }
    }

$stmt->close();
$stmt2->close();
```

Wanted to know if the variables contained data:

```
/* show data from the post*/
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($a1);
echo "</pre><br>";
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($a2);
echo "</pre><br>";
```

Turns out it does, it matches the input. Output:

```
 array(30) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  etc..
 }

 array(30) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  etc...
 }
```

All it does is store the word 'Array' in the places where there should be the input values. Can anyone point me in the right direction please? I'm stuck and could really use some help.

Edit: This is a for a simple website about soccer matches. Hobby project :D Value1 is the goals scored by the home team, and value 2 by the away team. And the $_POST is the input with goals scored for both teams for several matches for a specific user.

Edit2: Added code from the form where the is sent from and tables used:

```
//....connection, select query, etc....

$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$rows[] = $row;
}
?>

//....form and tabel stuff....
    <form action="send1.php" method="post"> 
        <div class="table-responsive">  
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Date</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-1">Time</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Home - Away</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-1">Home</th>
                        <th class="col-sm-1">Away</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>                                                                     
<?php

foreach($rows as $row){

?>                          
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2"><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1"><?php echo $row['time']; ?></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">
                            <span class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $row['Team_Home']; ?> - <?php echo $row['Team_Away']; ?></span>
                            <span class="visible-xs-block">test1 - test2</span>
                        </td>                                           
                        <td class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" name="score1[]" style="height:20px; width:32px"></td>   
                        <td class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" name="score2[]" style="height:20px; width:32px"></td>                                       
                    </tr>                                   
<?php  

}  

$result->close();

?>  

//....more table stuff with submit button...

<?php
mysqli_close();
?>
```

The output is like 10+ rows with input for goals scored by the home team and away team.

The table where the data comes from looks like this:

- **Matches**

  - Match_id
  - Date
  - Time
  - City
  - Stadion
  - Team_home
  - Team_away
  - Score_home
  - Score_away

And where the predictions go to looks like this at the moment:

- **Predictions**

  - Prediction_id
  - Match_id
  - User_id
  - Score_predict_home
  - Score_predict_away
  - Points

So I want all the match data in 1 table and the predictions in another.

Edit3: This is what I made of it now. No more php errors :D The data is in the array but doesn't end up in the db :(

```
$acMatchPredictions = !empty($_POST['match_prediction']) &&       
is_array($_POST['match_prediction']) ? $_POST['match_prediction'] : array();

foreach($acMatchPredictions as $wedstrijd_id => $aPredictedScores) {
    $score_predict_home = (int) $aPredictedScores['score_predict_home'];
    $score_predict_away = (int) $aPredictedScores['score_predict_away'];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$query = ('update predictions set score_predict_home=?, score_predict_away=? where match_id=? and user_id=?');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); 

$stmt->bind_param('iiii', $match_id, $user_id, $score_predict_home, $score_predict_away);

$stmt->execute();

}

$stmt->close();

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($acMatchPredictions);
echo "</pre><br>";
```

Output of the var_dump:

```
array(72) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["score_predict_home"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["score_predict_away"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["score_predict_home"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["score_predict_away"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
```

Comment: you can not store an array in a DB. you can, however, store a string encoding the array. try json_encode() and json_decode()

Comment: check form input field of value1 and value2...

Comment: Because you use example data in the question, it is not understandable what you trying to achieve. If your primary goal is just to store what array has, try the answer-comment by @FranzGleichmann (I recommend you to use JSON data type in database), if not; you have to store every item of your array as a separate column value.

Comment: Personally I'd recommend **not** storing JSON or serialized PHP data in the database ... with a well thought out system there should rarely be any reason to store serialized code at all.

Comment: Just to add some context. I'm trying to build a website about soccer matches. value1 is representing the predicted points scored by the home team, and value2 by the away team.

Comment: @CD001, Any idea how I can store the predicted points scored in my db using $_POST and no JSON?

Comment: @Henkie - oki, you asked for it ;)

Comment: You're not actually trapping errors from MySQL there, for instance `mysqli::prepare()` can return false if there's an error ... as can `mysqli::bind_param()` and `mysqli::execute()` - try trapping those with `if ... else` conditions and use something like `mysqli::error` to debug : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the full array use this:

```
recording $saveArray = serialize ($myArray);
```

get use array:

```
$myArray = unserialize($arrayInMysql);
```

If you save what's inside the loop put the past parameter within the foreach:

`$stmt->bind_param("ss", $ value, $ a3)`...

Comment: Tried the serialize bit. Don't know if it's correct, since I still get the word 'Array' in the database. But the print works. 

$b1 = $_POST['value1'];      
$a1 = serialize($b1);
print_r($b1);'

Comment: The data stored in the database will be seen as an Array type. After that, you can get the data with unserialize.

Answer (score 0):

If you're holding serialized application code in your database you're probably thinking about the system backwards. The database should model your requirements and the application should simply interface with it.

So, for football fixtures you'd probably want several tables in your database, something like:

**team**

- id
- name
- stadium_id

**stadium**

- id
- name

**match**

- id
- date
- stadium_id
- home_team_id
- home_team_score
- away_team_id
- away_team_score

**prediction**

- id
- match_id
- user_id
- home_team_score
- away_team_score
- points

Presumably these are match outcomes predicted by users of the site, hence the *user_id* column.

---

If I understand the question correctly, you're generating a list of matches and allowing peoople to set predictions on scores for them.

Your HTML form would now look something like:

```html
<form action="send1.php" method="post" style="font-family: sans-serif;">                 
<?php foreach($matches as $match): ?>

 <div class="fixture">
  <h2>Fixture</h2>
  <div class="fx date"><span>Date:</span> <?= $match['date']; ?></div>
  <div class="fx stadium"><span>Stadium:</span> <?= $match['stadium_name']; ?></div>

  <div class="fx home_team">
   <div class="title">Home Team : <?= $match['home_team_name']; ?></div>
   <div class="score"><label>Predicted score: 
    <input type="text" name="match_prediction[<?= $match['id']; ?>][home_score]" />
   </label></div>
  </div>

  <div class="fx away_team">
   <div class="title">Away Team : <?= $match['away_team_name']; ?></div>
   <div class="score"><label>Predicted score:
    <input type="text" name="match_prediction['<?= $match['id']; ?>][away_score]" />
   </label></div>
  </div>
 </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

This should give you a list of fixtures into which users can insert their score predictions.

The data is being passed through to PHP as array of arrays, using the match id as a key.

So, for matches 1, 12 and 34 the list of predictions might look like:

```
$_POST = array(
    match_prediction[1]['home_score'] = 1,
    match_prediction[1]['away_score'] = 2,
    match_prediction[12]['home_score'] = 3,
    match_prediction[12]['away_score'] = 1,
    match_prediction[34]['home_score'] = 2,
    match_prediction[34]['away_score'] = 2
);
```

To then get at that data to insert it into the database you can simply loop over the $_POST array:

```
$acMatchPredictions = !empty($_POST['match_prediction']) && is_array($_POST['match_prediction']) ? 
    $_POST['match_prediction'] :
    array();

foreach($acMatchPredictions as $iMatchId => $aPredictedScores) {
    $iHomeScore = (int) $aPredictedScores['home_score'];
    $iAwayScore = (int) $aPredictedScores['away_score'];
    $iUserId = {wherever your user id comes from, session?};

    //query to insert this prediction
    $sqy = "INSERT INTO prediction (match_id, user_id, home_team_score, away_team_score) "
        . "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";

    //prepare the statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);

    //bind parameters
    if(!$stmt->bind_param('iiii', $iMatchId, $iUserId, $iHomeScore, $iAwayScore)) {
        //trap the error ...
    }

    //execure and so on ...
    // ...

}
```

This follows the basic rules of database normalization:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

If you start putting serialized application code into your database then the database itself could become completely obsolete if/when you update the application. If you totally separate the data from the process (one of the principles behind MVC) you'll not face this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate anwser! I have tables (all data present except scores) and a form. Difference is that my form is generated from a while and foreach loop, and you can fill out multiple games at once. I need to update multiple rows with scores. Will post my table & form later.

Comment: Added form code and table info for a more complete view.

Comment: @Henkie updated the answer to closer match what you're after (I think)

Comment: When I print my new array set up I see all af the predictions. Rest isn't working yet and keep getting a 500. Gonna try a few adjustments.

Comment: @ CD001 I resolved all the errors and the output of the array is correct if i print it. But I don't see any updated data in my db.

Comment: Make sure you've got all error reporting enabled - odds are there's something falling over somewhere.

Comment: No errors. Maybe something wrong with the query or the foreach? Added code at the end of my post.